# discord bot not responding - python

Tags: python, discord

I am working on a discord bot in python, and it has suddenly stopped responding. Any reason why this might be happening?

Here is my code;

import discord

```
TOKEN = '(censored)'

client = discord.Client()

prefix = '!'

playername = []

playercredits = []

@client.event

async def on_message(message):


if message.content.startswith(prefix + 'hi'):
    msg = f'Hi baldy.'
    await message.channel.send(msg)

@client.event
```

`async def on_ready()`:

```
 print('------')
print(client.user.name)

print(client.user.id)



 print('------')
```

client.run(TOKEN)

if you have any idea why my bot isn't responding, please assist me. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

**on_message** is overriding the default provided on_message which forbids any extra commands from running. To fix this, add a client.process_commands(message) line at the end of your on_message. For example:

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    # do some extra stuff here

    await client.process_commands(message)
```